# Historical data on EUA Futures (Intraday, 15 minutes) from 2008

Tags: historical-data, intraday, european

I'm actually working on carbon markets.
Anyone knows where I could find EUA (european union allowances) futures prices intraday (15 minutes) from 2008 until now **for free**?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Tick Data](https://www.tickdata.com). They sell trade (and optionally quote) data for a lot of different instruments including the EUA futures. Their pricing is 125 USD for a one year tick history and you need to order for at least 250 USD at a time.

I ordered some Eurex DAX future tick history from them. The order process was flawless and their pricing was significantly cheaper than other providers I could find (incl. Eurex directly).

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately I cannot afford to pay 8 years of data..

Comment: I don't think you will be able to find 8 years of intraday data for free. A standard Bloomberg subscription usually gives you sth. like 1 year of historical intraday data and the 125 USD/year from the above provider was the cheapest I could find when I looked for Eurex data myself. Please let us know should your search be successful!